# C# LINQ selecting a list with a property that has multiple value

Tags: c#, linq

I have this list which has the following value

```
id, name, List<Tag>
```

where `Tag` has 2 data, `TagID` and `TagName`

Now I want to use linq to select the list with this output

```
id1, name1, tagid1, tag1
id1, name1, tagid2, tag2
id1, name1, tagid3, tag3
id2, name2, tagid4, tag4
```

How to do this in linq?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use [`SelectMany`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.selectmany?view=netframework-4.8):

```
list.SelectMany(item => item.Tags.Select(tag => new { item.Id, item.Name, tag.Id, tag.Tag }));
```